# Reuse keys in hashtable in java

Tags: java

If I have a HashTable of like

```
HashTable<Person, Salary> Salaries
```

And an unrelated one like

```
HashTable<Person, Car> Cars
```

With unrelated I mean, that Object reference of Person is expected to be different, but we know that we are talking by the same Persons, with the same first and last-name. 
I can find the key using Salaries.entrySet(), I know that the person has a car. Is it valid to use the Keys to find the corresponding car in the Cars HashTable? And what if instead of Person, Integer was used?

Comment: Why do you have two different instances which are supposed to refer to the same `Person`? That seems like a design flaw (in reality there's many different people with the same first and last name)

Comment: Yes, in my particular case, the case that triggered the question, it is a object that represents a point, st like (int x, int y). But I don't know how it is exactly implemented. Which should be the case for object orientated programming.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer:

If the `Person` object you used to store a `Salary` object into the `salaries` Hashtable and the `Person` object you used to store a `Car` object into the `cars` Hashtable are **[equal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)**, you can use either one to retrieve the other.

### Now, what does this mean...

What equal means, is defined by [`Object.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). If you don't overwrite this method, only identical objects are equal, i.e. an *instance equals itself only*. In this case, you can't use the different `Person` objects.

You might want to **overwrite `equals`** to check whether the *values representing the object* are equal. This obviously assumes that you can modify the `Person` class.

This assumes you're talking of **different instances** of **the same class** representing the same person and not different instances of **different classes**.

Generally, `equals` should only return true for an object of **the same class** (even subclasses are a problem). So if your `Person` objects are of **different classes** (more like a `SalaryPerson` and `CarPerson`) or if you can't change them, you might want to implement a `PersonKey` class that extracts the data relevant for equality (name, ...) and use this as a key.

### Using Integer as key:

According to the [JavaDoc of the Integer class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/Integer.html), `Integer.equals(Integer)` returns true if both integer objects to have the same `int` value. In other words: using `Integer` as a key in a `Hashtable` will retrieve objects by the integer value of the key.

### Caveats:

- [`Object.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) has to be *consistent* with `equals`. In short, if you overwrite `equals`, you must also overwrite `hashCode` and make sure it returns the same hash code for all objects that `equals` considers equal.
- You have to make sure that the values used by equal don't change during object lifetime (or at least as long as they serve as a key for the Hashtable...) - otherwise retrieving will fail! It is often suggested that the fields used in equals should be **`final`**

### By the way:

- According to the [Java Code Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf), variable names start with a lowercase letter. I therefore call your Hashtables `salaries` and `cars`.
- [`HashMap<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is much more common in Java than  [`Hashtable<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html). Hashtable is usually only used if a synchronized implementation is needed.

### See also:

- [Java Practices](http://www.javapractices.com) has a good articles about [`equals`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) and about [`hashCode`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=28).
- For an in depth article about `equals` see [Angelika Langer's "Secrets of equals()"](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/JavaSolutions/SecretsOfEquals/Equals.html)
- "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch shows the way around all the intricate parts of Java

Answer (score 0):

Keys in your hashtable are retrieved based on the object equality. So if you have the equals and hashcode overriden in Person class, it should be perfectly possible to retrieve the values from 2 different hashtables.

Integers can also be used. It would be like retrieving the values of Key "1" from both the hashtables.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it valid to use the Keys to find the corresponding car in the Cars HashTable

sure it is

To provide this possibility you should override your `hashCode` and `equals` methods and implement the way to compare two values - for example (let's assume that Person class contains some `id` field with unique values)

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Person p = (Person) o;

    return getId().equals(p.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getId().hashCode();
}
```

Then if you will take a look at `equals` implementation of `java.lang.Integer` (1.8) you will see

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}

public static int hashCode(int value) {
    return value;
}
```

what does mean that this Integer class is being compared by value - so it will fit your requirements

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon different condition:

1) If the person object reference in keyset of first HashTable is  referring to the exactly same object in second HashTable, then it would be fine to use the same key to the car for the person.

2) There might be a case where  two person having same first name and last name but different object. In this that hash value would be different so the key in HashTable. In this case  you cannot use the same key.

If you are using integer as a key in HashTable then it would fine in your scenario.

Hope this would be helpful.